# A dangerous Request.Form when value entered into a textbox

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I have a simple aspx page through which i am entering Text into a textbox the text are coming though texteditor so the text are with html tags.

Such as `<p>My name</p>`

the error which i am getting is like:

```
Server Error '/' Application 
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder2$TxtTopicName="<p>kdarftghjh</p>").
```

What type of error is this and how could i resolve such error.Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using webforms you can add the following to your page-declaration:

```
validateRequest="false"
```

Comment: thanks sir it works for me. But why this type of error?? Posting with html tags is dangerous

Comment: That's because if you allow users to include tags, you could open your site for XSS attacks.

Answer (score 2):

You are having html tags in this input(`<`,`>`). just remove it or encode it. of if you really need to do like this try adding following part to web.config

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
     <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
  </system.web>
  <pages validateRequest="false">
  </pages>
</configuration>
```